# SP2013 - Excel two way sync

Tags: excel

So I've been asked to create a setup where the user can copy a rather large amount of info into an Excel file and then have it synced to the connected SP list.

I've found several articles about the old - but yet still working - Add-in solution to Excel. And while that does work - once you accept you can't use it on existing lists -  it seem rather fragile. For instance if I was to delete the master file by accident I would have no way to restore the connection.

That simply don't seem right, so i tried to export the connection settings and reimport it, however that didn't work.

Do anybody have any clue how to restore the connection? Or even better how to create the connection to an existing list?

Comment: you problem might be here '(...)large amount of info into an Excel file', Why not copy it to to Sharepoint list in datasheet directly? if it is few thousand rows it should work. If its more you should probably stay away from lists anyway and look at hosting and Access DB for that.

Comment: We need to be able to update the information in a monthly basis. But you're not really getting the point of my question - we need to handle this in a list. And we need two way synchronizing of data.